# Filter column from file based on header matching a regex

Tags: file, awk, filter

I have the following file

```
foo_foo   bar_blop   baz_N  toto_N    lorem_blop
1          1         0      0         1
1          1         0      0         1
```

And I'd like to remove the columns with the `_N` tag on header (or selecting all the others)

So the output should be

```
foo_foo   bar_blop   lorem_blop
1          1         1
1          1         1
```

I found some answers but none were doing this exactly
I know awk can do this but I don't understand how to do it by myself (I'm not good at awk) with this language.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==1 {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ( (tgt == "") || ($i !~ tgt) ) {
            f[++nf] = i
        }
    }
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=nf; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", $(f[i]), (i<nf?OFS:ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -v tgt="_N" -f tst.awk file | column -t
foo_foo  bar_blop  lorem_blop
1        1         1
1        1         1

$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -t
foo_foo  bar_blop  baz_N  toto_N  lorem_blop
1        1         0      0       1
1        1         0      0       1

$ awk -v tgt="blop" -f tst.awk file | column -t
foo_foo  baz_N  toto_N
1        0      0
1        0      0
```

The main difference between this and [@Kent's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37303272/1745001) is performance and the impact will vary based on the percentage of fields you want to print on each line.

The above when reading the first line of the file creates an array of the field numbers to print and then for every line of the input file it just prints those fields in a loop. So if you wanted to print 3 out of 100 fields then this script would just loop through 3 iterations/fields on each input line.

@Kent's solution also creates an array of the field numbers to print but then for every line of the input file it visits every field to test if it's in that array before printing or not. So if you wanted to print 3 out of 100 fields then @Kent's script would loop through all 100 iterations/fields on each input line.

Answer (score 2):

```
 awk 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(!($i~/_N$/)){a[i]=1;m=i}}
 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(a[i])printf "%s%s",$i,(i==m?RS:FS)}' f|column -t
```

outputs:

```
foo_foo  bar_blop  lorem_blop
1        1         1
1        1         1
```

Comment: @jas yep, saving "not_to_removed" index in `m` should fix it.. check the updated answer

Comment: That will have unnecessarily poor performance. I added an explanation at the end of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37303876/1745001).

Comment: @EdMorton true. looping in saved index-array should be faster. And I would leave my answer there without further changes, so that readers can understand the comment in your answer well...

Comment: thanks for leaving it up, it is important that people be able to see the 2 alternatives and understand the differences.